# Connect to MySQL on Google Compute Engine from App Engine and externally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I successfully created a Compute Engine VM instance, and installed MySQL on it using this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql

Now I want to connect to it from App Engine and from my home too if possible.
Using this guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/connecting-vpc
I created the connector, giving it the suggested 10.x.x.x/28 IP address.

In my app engine's app.yaml I inserted:
vpc_access_connector:
name: projects/xxxxxxxxxx/locations/europe-west3/conectors/xxxxxx

The VM instance shows an internal IP of 10.x.x.x and an external IP of 34.x.x.x

I am trying to connect from PHP using this line:
new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306, null);
but I get different errors.

When connecting to 34.x.x.x from my home:
mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
(I even created a Firewall rule to allow all traffic from my home IP)

When connecting to10.x.x.x from app engine:
2002: Connection timed out

When connecting to 10.x.x.x from app engine:
2002: Connection refused

How can I make a connection?

Comment: Can you log into the MySQL host VM and try to connect you to your MySQL instance directly from there?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that the service inside the instance is not up and running, check if the service of MySQL is running and listening,  you can try this by doing a [nmap test](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-nmap-debian-ubuntu-server-desktop-system/) vs. the public IP of your MySQL VM instance `nmap 34.0.0.0`. You should see something like this (if you are using the standard port):

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

Remember that there are two firewalls you need to take care of on GCP, (VPC firewall & OS firewall). So if you are not able to see this port start the SQL service by connecting into your VM instance and typing `sudo systemctl start mysql`, now run again `nmap 34.0.0.0` and you should see the service.

To connect from App Engine to MySQL on Compute Engine VM instance just follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#configuring) other guide .

To connect from your home It will be better for you to connect to the instance [via SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools) and then to access your database, or you can keep connecting by a VPN to access it with the internal IP address if you need to connect directly to the socket, just take care to avoid hitting the limitations or missing something like [IAM roles and permission](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#curated_iam_roles) needed for this connection.

Comment: I just ran into your edit in which you anonymized the IP addresses. May I ask why do you consider that sharing the IP address and especially the _public_ IP address represents a threat? Any reference would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I installed nmap, and running the command with the public IP I got the following:
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server

Mysql is not present anywhere, and even after giving the command:
sudo systemctl start mysql,
nothing changes.

Comment: @NeoAnderson I edited the external IP address by personal decision as previously the project ID, internal IP's and VPN name were exposed, just to shield all the post and by the fact the external IP address is not relevant to the troubleshoot.

Comment: @BalintFodor So the main issue here is that the installation was not successful or there is a misconfiguration by following the guide: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql, I already did it and expose the service as intended.Try it again taking care of each step

Comment: Thanks, I did figure it out. There was nothing wrong with the installation, I don't know why nmap shows me different data. The solution is here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1032130/connect-to-mysql-on-google-compute-engine-from-app-engine-and-externally